# ¿Cómo crear una tabla Factura para una aplicación comercial usando PostgreSQL?

Tags: base-de-datos, postgresql, aplicación-web

La duda es la siguiente: Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación web para un comercio y estoy utilizando PostreSQL para el diseño de la base de datos pero en la parte web estoy utilizando como tal HQL.

Se requiere que las facturas conserven una secuencia lógica, para ello utilizo el campo increment y no hay problema. Pero he notado que cuando por alguna razón debo borrar algún registro, dicho campo se pierde por completo y queda una secuencia incompleta. Por ejemplo si se borra el registro número 4. La base de datos queda con el registro 3 y 5 pero el 4 queda borrado por completo (Esto es un gran problema para las empresas en general en materia fiscal).

¿Cómo debo manejar este tipo de situación? ¿Qué me sugieren para solucionar este inconveniente?

Gracias por la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

Answer (score 0):

Existen 2 métodos para "borrar" los datos de una tabla en una base de datos:

El **borrado físico**: consiste en la eliminación del registro de la base de datos. En este caso, se borra del disco duro y en un futuro será "imposible" recuperarlo. El problema es que para preservar la integridad de los datos, se debe eliminar el registro y todos los registros que estén relacionados en cascada. Por eso, se recomienda el borrado lógico ya que hoy en día no tenemos problemas de espacio a la hora de almacenar información.

```
DELETE FROM tabla WHERE id = ?
```

El **borrado lógico**: consiste en cambiar a inactivo/eliminado el estado de un registro. La principal ventaja es que se puede deshacer el borrado cambiando a activo el estado del registro.

Se debe agregar una nueva columna *(el nombre puede ser "estado", "eliminado" o cualquier otro)* a la tabla, la cuál nos va a indicar si el registro se encuentra activo (1) o borrado (0).

```
// Eliminar un registro
UPDATE tabla SET estado = 0 WHERE id = ?
// Deshacer la eliminación del registro
UPDATE tabla SET estado = 1 WHERE id = ?
```

Incluso, un mejor enfoque es usar un campo de estado que sea más preciso (activo, discontinuado, cancelado, eliminado, etc) en función del caso de estudio que estamos modelando.

---

En tu caso te sugiero utilizar un borrado lógico de las facturas utilizando un campo estado que permita el valor *"Activo"* para las que son válidas y *"Anulado"* para las que tuvieron errores a la hora de la facturación.